# Showing NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

Clicking menu item shows a NSWindow, but only for first time, why is so that, and how to fix it?

```
-(IBAction)menuClick:(id)sender
{   
    if (!formsView) {
        formsView = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Forms"];
    }

    [formsView showWindow:self];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the same code I use and it works. The problem must be elsewhere.

The problem isn't the code, it's the setup in Interface Builder. (I'm still using Xcode 3.2 so in my world Interface builder is a separate application.) Make sure the class for *File's Owner* in the xib is set to `NSWindowController` and that its `window` outlet is connected to the window.

If you don't do this and *Visible At Launch* is set for the window, you'll get exactly the symptom you describe. This is because `initWithWindowNibName` loads the NIB file and the window is shown because of the *Visible At Launch* flag. But if you look at the `window` property of your `NSWindowController` instance you'll see that it is still nil. That's why the window isn't redisplayed when you call `showWindow` again. It's the connections in IB that associate the window with the controller.

[Here's a project that has IB set up correctly.](http://theuniversalsteve.com/files/so6962531.zip)

Here's the relevant settings in IB:

[image: The relevant settings for IB]

Comment: can you provide simple example application with this code works, please?

Comment: This was really, really helpful: I was struggling because I'm initialising a `NSWindowController` with `NSWindowController(windowNibName:)` and the window property was *always* nil, not only before actually showing the new window by calling `showWindow:`. I did find recommendation of setting the window property elsewhere, but I did not realise it was File's Owner that had to be set as `NSWindowController`, and that its' `window` outlet that had to be connected with the window. This image made a lot of difference for me, so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you uncheck the "release when closed" checkbox in Interface Builder (not built into Xcode 4) for the window?

Comment: yeah, it's unchecked, take a look - https://img.skitch.com/20110806-bwf1kifdb195ssm6i5gj6mb3f1.jpg

Comment: Is your window controller's (File owner's in Interface Builder) "window" outlet connected to the window?

Comment: Just above your "[formsView showWindow:self];", can you please add "NSLog(@"window: %@", [formsView window]);" and see what it prints?

Comment: both first (when it's work) and second time it log this:"window: (null)"

Comment: Seems strange to me. Can you please isolate your code into a simple sample application, and see if it still doesn't work? If it doesn't, feel free to show us the code.